# Как проверить, открыто ли стороннее приложение?

Tags: windows, qt, c++

Перед строчкой кода:

```
QAxObject *mExcel = new QAxObject("Excel.Application",this);
```

хотелось бы проверить, не открыта ли сама программа Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что Ваше приложение не будет кроссплатформенным, так что я бы рекомендовал использовать нативное для Windows PSAPI.

Надо получить все имена выполняющихся процессов и проверить, нет ли в этих именах Excel.

Полная документация по PSAPI здесь:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx